# Prefered style using public/private statements in Fortran?

Tags: scope, fortran, private, public

For example:

```
module m_a
  private
  integer :: x, y
  public :: x
end module m_a

module m_b
  public
  integer :: x, y
  private :: y
end module m_b
```

Obviously the variables `x` and `y` have equivalent scope in module `m_a` and `m_b`. My question is which one is preferred from the point of view of programming style?

In most tutorial of Fortran 90/95, style of module `m_a` is adopted. However, for a large project, which contains a complicated hierarchy of hundreds of modules, I've noticed significant longer compilation time of sytle `m_a` than that of style `m_b`.

I have not found similar topic discussed. Maybe I've misused `public/private` statements in module hierarchy? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

Style m_a is preferred, where the default is made private, and items are explicitly declared public.  With this approach the programmer can readily identify which items are exported (public) by the module.  With the other approach this information is difficult to figure out.  Assisting the programmer in understanding the module is more important than compilation time.

Comment: A further consideration is that things implicitly defined inside m_b become public entities when that may not be what was intended.  Entities such as implied do indicies or intrinsic functions referenced in an initializer, etc.